How to implement and notate the replication/transformation of a 2D matrix to a 3D tensor and the summation/transformation of a 3D tensor to 2D matrix?
Background:
I have a model with a dimension $T$ representing $time$, a dimension $N$ representing $technologies$ and a dimension $P$ representing $prices$. During calculations in this model, I would like to add the $T$ dimension (replicate data for each time step) and I would like to remove the $N$ dimension (sum N).
I have to implement this model in numpy and document it mathematically. How can I

implement and notate the replication/transformation of a 2D matrix to a 3D tensor?
implement and notate the summation/transformation of a 3D tensor to 2D matrix?

On the one hand the notation should use mathematic operators/operations that track used numpy operations as close as possible but also keep the mathematic documentation correct and readable for users without a math degree (like me). On the other hand, used numpy operations should be expressable with mathematic operators/concepts.
Sometimes different mathematic operations seems to have the same mathematic notation. In other cases, it seems to me, that one mathematic operation can be denoted with different operators and in some cases one mathematic operation seems to have many possible numpy implementations.
If there is not a right or wrong answer, I would be interested in an opinion, convention or best practice. I was not sure if this fits better to stack exchange mathematics, stackoverflow or this platform.

Replicating dimensions
From 1D to 2D: I have a row vector $A \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times P}$. Now, I would like to replicate this vector to a matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times P}$, e.g. each technology  should have identical prices. I thought about notating this as Kronecker Product with a one vector:
$C^{N \times P} = 1^{N \times 1} \otimes A^{1 \times P}$
C_NxP = np.kron(one_Nx1, A_1xP)

From 2 Dto 3D: Now, I would like to transofrm this $C^{N \times P}$ matrix to a $D \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N \times P}$ tensor, e.g. each time step has the same technologies and prices. I thought about notating this as tensor product which seems to have the same symbol as Kronecker Product
$D^{T \times N \times P} = 1^{T \times 1} \otimes C^{N \times P}$
D_Tx1xNxP = np.tensordot(One_Tx1, C_NxP, axes=0) # error: returns Tx1xNxP

But the corresponding numpy operation returns the wrong shape if $1^{T \times 1}$ is an actual numpy column vector (shape Tx1) and I would prefer to not explicitly reshape from 2D to 1D numpy vectors. However, with np.einsum it works:
D_TxNxP = np.einsum('io,jk->ijk', One_Tx1, C_NxP)

Therefore, would it be better to notate this as $T_{ijk} = D_{i1} \cdot C_{jk}$ ? Is Tensorproduct and Einstein sum here identical? If yes, could I denote this as Tensorproduct?

Summing/reducing dimension:
From 2D to 1D: I have $G \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N}$ and I would like to sum the technologies per time step. I thought to notate this as matrix multiplication:
$E^{T \times 1} = C^{T \times N} * 1^{N \times 1}$
E_Tx1 = G_TxN @ 1_Nx1

From 3D to 2D: Now, I would like to apply this to the tensor $D \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times N \times P}$ and sum technology values of each price level p, e.g. sum the "inner" matrix ${N \times P}$ by dimension N. It seems like the Einstein sum convention works again.
$M_{tp} = B_{tnp} \, C_n$
M_TxP = np.einsum('tnp,n->tp', B_TxNxP, C_Nx1)  

But as far as I understood, I could also denote this as n-mode product which looks more readable to me:
$M^{T \times P} = B^{T \times N  \times P} \times_{\!N}\, C^{N \times 1}$
Would that be correct?
